# Register a .dll or .ocx in c++

Tags: c++, regsvr32

I am trying to register a dll from my code`(Windows 7, 64-bit Application)`. I opened my application with administrator rights. You can see the code snippet below.

```
hinst = ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), L"regsvr32.exe", str, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
str -> fully qualified path of the file like  C:\\XXXX\\XXXX\\XXXX.dll"
```

The ShellExecute returns the following:`"0x0000002a"` and fails to register the file

What could be the issue?

Comment: A `>=32` exit code means that the `ShellExecute` launched the executable correctly, does `regsvr32` give some particular error message?

Comment: A window pops up saying. The module C:\XXXX\XXX failed to load.. blah blah ..... The specified module could not be found

Comment: ... which means that the dll couldn't be found. Double check its path, as shown in the error message, and verify that the file is actually there.

Comment: The dll is in the exact location. When i try the same path from command prompt. It works well

Comment: Maybe it's on a network share mounted on a drive letter?

Comment: No it is not, i tried the same thing from multiple .dlls in multiple locations but none gets registered. Is it anyway related to 32 bit or 64 bit regsvr32 ?

Comment: That can be as well, although I'd expect a different error message, unless file system redirection is in place... What path exactly are you using?

Comment: I am using path of the .dll on my C: Drive

Comment: Again, what is the *exact* path? It's important to determine if it's one of the locations normally enabled for file system redirection.

Comment: Why does this scenario fail ?  1. I opened my command prompt with administrator rights 2. Then used regsvr32  "the path of the .dll" . It fails to register.  Path of my dll is " C:\Cabinet Vision\Common\PXJSite.dll"

Comment: I found that problem is with space in the path (folder name). It works when the path is C:\NewFolder\Test.dll  and fails when path is  C:\New Folder\Test.dll .